# why YARN_FLAGS are being ignored?

Tags: netlify

I'm having hard time figuring out why YARN_FLAGS are not being used

```
# Related to YARN_FLAGS https://git.io/fx1W5  https://git.io/fx1RF  # debug with --verbose
[build]
  base    = "./services/frontend"
  command = "echo $YARN_FLAGS && yarn build" 
  publish = "./services/frontend/build"

[build.environment]
  NODE_VERSION = "10.12.0"
  YARN_FLAGS = "--ignore-optional --frozen-lockfile --network-timeout 1000000 --network-concurrency 1 --verbose"

[context.production.environment]
  NODE_ENV = "production"

[context.deploy-preview.environment]
  NODE_ENV = "test"

[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

https://app.netlify.com/sites/monstereos-gabo/deploys/5bd08b5bc965924622aeccce

Comment: Shouldn't `[[redirects]]` be `[redirects]`? Maybe it's a syntax issue that's failing silently.

Comment: nope @JeanLescure that is the correct syntax for redirects.  There can be many of them; all need that identical header.

Answer (score 2):

The [Netlify docs tell us that they make specific decisions](https://www.netlify.com/docs/build-settings/#build-environment-variables) based on whether there is a `yarn.lock` vs a `package.lock` and how it handles the `YARN_FLAGS`.

> If you have a /yarn.lock file: you can set YARN_VERSION (any released version), YARN_FLAGS (flags to pass to our automatic yarn install that **runs when this file is present**). YARN_FLAGS is set to --ignore-optional by default. /package.json file is ignored in regards to the next step below if you have a /yarn.lock!

Make sure to push your `yarn.lock` file to your repository. It looks like the build process decides to use the flags environment variable when the lock file exists.

***Note:*** You may want to trigger a deploy and `Clear build cache` for good measure after you push your `yarn.lock` file to your repository.

[image]